# remove everything but the filename php

Tags: php

I'm trying to get rid of everything before the filename ex:

```
/home/mike/whatever/test_1.txt
```

leaving only `test_1.txt`

what would the simplest way?

thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`basename()`](https://www.php.net/basename)

Comment: Quite possibly the best answer I've seen on stackoverflow.

Comment: Ditto to the previous comments.